# Return from jquery to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

So I'm pretty new to Javascript and even newer to jQuery. Working on this project atm, I started with Javascript but a lot of the solution to my issues were a lot easier in jQuery.

so I have some javascript which basically prevents the user from pressing submit if all the forms have not passed validation.

So this is my field.

```
<td><input type="password" maxlength="16" name="passwd" id="passwd" onblur="validatePassword(this.value)" /></td>
<td><span id="pMess"></span></td>
```

This is my submit.

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return validate(this.form)"/></td>
<td><a href='Index.php'>Login?</a></td>
```

As you can see when you press submit it goes to the validate function which is:

```
function validate(theForm) {
    var valid = true;

    if ( !validateEmail(theForm.emailrec.value) ) valid = false;
    if ( !validatePassword(theForm.passwd.value) ) valid = false;
    if ( !validatePostcode(theForm.postcode.value) ) valid = false;
    if ( valid ) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

And finally this is the field checker.

```
function validatePassword(passwordString) {
   var valid = true;

   if ( passwordString == "" ) {
      feedback('pMess','Enter your password here');
      valid = false;
   } else if ( passwordString.length <= 5 ){
      feedback('pMess','Password too short');
      valid = false;
   } else feedback('pMess','Acceptable');

   if ( valid ) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

My username field checker is slighty different as it's in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').keyup(username_check);
});

function username_check() { 
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if(username == "" || username.length < 6){
        $('#username').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
        $('#tick').hide();
        $('#cross').fadeIn();
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",
            data: 'username=' + username,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 1) {
                    $('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
                    $('#tick').hide();
                    $('#cross').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
                    $('#cross').hide();
                    $('#tick').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

so what I'm trying to do is get username_check to return like my other field checkers. I'm just looking for help as to where I should put the returns and stuff. Whatever I try seems to break the code...

All I have so far

```
 if ( !check_username(theForm.username.value) ) valid = false;
```

Any help at pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: ..there is no return from jQuery..

Comment: even though you are new to javascript or jQuery, is there any reason why you can't use jQuery for everything that relates to DOM?

Comment: Well I'm hoping to change everything to jQuery but still learning so in all good time...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not jQuery.  The problem is that you are using an **asynchronous** call to do some of your validation.  `jQuery.ajax` is asynchronous, meaning that code will continue to execute while it fetches `check.php`.  In other words, by the time the response comes back, `username_check()` will have already returned and submitted your form (or cancelled the submit).

For the non-AJAX part of your code (the length check), you can do a `return` just fine:

```
function username_check() { 
    var username = $('#username').val();

    // NOTE: This is redundant, as "" has length 0
    if(username == "" || username.length < 6){ 
        $('#username').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
        $('#tick').hide();
        $('#cross').fadeIn();
        return false;   // This will work here
    } else {
        // AJAX stuff
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the rest gets a bit more tricky.  What you really want to do, is wait to sumbit your form until the username check is done, which means your submit needs to go in the callback function (i.e. the `success` part of your AJAX).  If you only have one AJAX call, this is not too bad.  If you have multiple AJAX calls, you need to either nest all of the calls (which makes the code take longer, is not very pretty, and will not easily proceed to other checks after one fails) or you need to use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (or something similar), which are not trivial (but very useful).

Assuming you have a single AJAX call for username:

First, add an ID to your submit button.  This makes it easier to reference from jQuery:

```
<td><input id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return validate(this.form)"/></td>
<td><a href='Index.php'>Login?</a></td>
```

Secondly, do the username check after all of the other checks, and only submit if the other checks were valid:

```
function validate(theForm) {
    var valid = true;

    if ( !validateEmail(theForm.emailrec.value) ) valid = false;
    if ( !validatePassword(theForm.passwd.value) ) valid = false;
    if ( !validatePostcode(theForm.postcode.value) ) valid = false;

    // The non-AJAX checks for username length:
    var username = theForm.username.value;
    if ( !validateUsername(username) ) valid = false;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check.php",
        data: 'username=' + username,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 1) {
                $('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
                $('#tick').hide();
                $('#cross').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
                $('#cross').hide();
                $('#tick').fadeIn();

                // If the other checks were OK, submit the form manually
                if(valid) {
                    $("#mysubmit").submit();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // ALWAYS return false.  
    // We will submit the form manually if the checks are OK
    // For now, prevent the submit
    return false;
}
```

Make sense?

Notes:

- You probably want to disable the submit button after it is clicked (and re-enable it on failure.  Otherwise, if the AJAX takes a while, a user could potentially change the field values before its callback, allowing bad data to be submitted without checks.
- The other solution to this is to do the checks `onsubmit`.  **Currently, your checks are not called if the user pressed the enter key.  This is bad!**

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I follow, you want the function to return true or false if validates, right?

Edit: my code was crap, thanks roasted for pointing that out.

So, as you are doing an ajax call you can't really get if it's valid (true or false) in the same function, you probably need to do something different....

A couple of ideas; 
-Use your DOM (add an "invalid" class or something like that to the form field and then check for that value.

-Use a global variable "valid_user" saving the result of the validation... ( i know global variables suck and it's a bad practice, but hey, if you have a deadline...)

then, when you are validating the hole form, check for this things instead of calling username_check again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As ajax is asynchronous, your return result will be always undefined